# Parenthesis in Spacebars template helper call throws error

Tags: meteor

The [Meteor Spacebar docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#nested-sub-expressions) say *"one can use parentheses to express the evaluation order of nested expressions"* and give this example:

```
{{capitalize (getSummary post)}}
```

However, I get a error on build anytime I use parenthesis:

> => Errors prevented startup:
>      While building the application:
>      client/templates/test.html:6: Expected identifier, number, string,
>      boolean, or null
>      ...        {{capitalize (getSummary post)}} ...

This error does not occur when the parenthesis are removed; of course then the expressions aren't evaluated properly.

For context, this is my intention (using *handlebar-helpers* and *meteor-roles*)

```
{{#if $or (isInRole "someRole") (isInRole "someOtherRole")}}
  <p>approved!</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: It is in `devel` branch, I don't think it is released yet.

Comment: You can use {{#if isInRole 'someRole, someOtherRole'}} for now.

Comment: it's on other branches as well: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.1.1/packages/spacebars/README.md

Comment: 1.1.1 was never released, we're currently at 1.1.0.2, and it's not in the current release for sure : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.1/packages/spacebars/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature in [1.1.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.1.1/packages/spacebars/README.md); it is not available in [1.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.1/packages/spacebars/README.md).